finite Fourier series transform in Matlab without the built in functions
I want to code the finite Fourier transform of a signal x(t) given xt and t are row vectors of x(t) and t, n, T as input parameters and xhat and Ck as the outputs.
I wrote down the code but it's giving me errors and I don't know how to fix them.
function [xhat, ck] = ffs(xt, t, n, T)

    xhat = zeros(size(t));
    ck = zeros(1, 2*n+1);
    
    for k = -n:n

        ck_index = k + n + 1; % Index starts from 1 and make sure index is positive
        funct= @(tau) xt.* exp(-1j .* 2 .* pi .* k .* tau ./ T);
        ck(ck_index) = 1/T * integral(funct,-T/2, T/2);
        
        xhat = xhat + ck(ck_index) * exp(1j * 2 * pi * k * t / T);
    end
end

It keeps on giving me that the input parameters are not of equal size.

Please post the entire error message. What arguments do you pass to your function? I'll fix your code formatting for you. Please check the edit to see how to format your code properly.

Please read [mre]. We need to know how you call the function (what are the input arguments?) and we need to see the full error message (copy-paste the text from the console, including the stack trace; don’t paraphrase).
